# How to keep @LastModifiedBy field empty (null) when creating a new entity, set only on update

Tags: java, spring, jpa, entity, auditing

Spring JPA auditable entity contains fields similar to this:

```
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
...
{
  @CreationTimestamp
  @Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false)
  @JsonIgnore
  private LocalDateTime createdDate;

  @CreatedBy
  @Column(name = "created_by", nullable = false)
  @JsonIgnore
  private Long createdBy;

  @UpdateTimestamp
  @Column(name = "modified_date")
  @JsonIgnore
  private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;

  @LastModifiedBy
  @Column(name = "modified_by")
  @JsonIgnore
  private Long lastModifiedBy;
}
```

**createdBy** and **lastModifiedBy** are IDs of an User that created the entity.

The fields are set by Spring JPA auditing in a similar manner:

```
  @Bean
  public AuditorAware<Long> auditorProvider() {
    return () -> {
      AppUserPrincipal principal = AuthUtils.getCurrentUser();
      return Optional.of(principal.getUserId());
    };
  }
```

By default, when a new entity is created, the IDs createdBy and lastModifiedBy have the same values (and dates).

**How to set lastModifiedBy and lastModifiedDate only when the entity is updated, not set them with the creator's values initially?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a neat solution to remove @UpdateTimestamp and @LastModifiedBy annotations, and use [JPA Entity Lifecycle events](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-lifecycle-events).

Example on how I created my @PreUpdate hook to set modifier values:

```
@PreUpdate
public void edit() {
    AppUserPrincipal user = AuthUtils.getCurrentUser();
    this.setLastModifiedDate(LocalDateTime.now());
    this.setLastModifiedBy(user.getUserId());
}
```